# How to break the components of a vector perpendicular to another?

Tags: vectors

[image]

Here , how should we break down the components of T here. Like we can’t make a triangle here since angle of mg with T here is 90. Then , how should we draw and make the T components.

2nd diagram just tells us that if there was an angle theta. Then , it was easy to Ames the components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, you don't break a vector up into components if it is already lined up with an axis.  If you have $m\overrightarrow{g}$ pointing in the $-y$ direction, for example, and $\overrightarrow{T}$ points in the $+x$ direction, then there's no need to break them up.  The components of $m\overrightarrow{g}$ in that case would be $(0, -mg)$ and the components of $\overrightarrow{T}$ would be $(T,0)$.

Comment: How would the diagram look like ?

Comment: It would look exactly like your first drawing.  The whole point of components is to make things perpendicular.  If they already are, you're done.

Comment: Ohk. Thanks a lot.